# How to save state of the app when app terminates?

Tags: iphone

I am trying to save the app state by encoding when the app terminates.
I've found the solution related this issue.
But I don't know how to use.

I am really trying to make encoding and decoding like this: 
http://cocoaheads.byu.edu/wiki/nscoding

in CustomObject.h

```
@interface CustomObject : NSObject <NSCoding>
{
   NSArray *someArray;
}
```

in CustomObject.m

```
@implementation CustomObject

// Other method implementations here

- (void) encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder*)encoder {
    [encoder encodeObject:someArray forKey:@"someArray"];
}

- (id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder*)decoder {
    if (self = [super init]) {
      someArray = [[decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"someArray"] retain];
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

My object to save is another NSArray. Not "someArray" in CustomObject. We call it that "MySaveObject".
I want to pass "MySaveObject" to "someArray" in CustomObject.

Actually I don't know how to encode "MySaveObject" and to pass to "someArray" in CustomObject.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make sure that the objects contained in the array are also able to be encoded. If those objects are custom objects, you'll have to implement `NSCoding` in them yourself.